# Migrate Angular 4 wih system.js toAngular 8 not working

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I am using Angular 4 with system.js and I do not have angular-cli.json

I am upgrading it to Angular 8. I did changes using below link:

[Issue after upgrading Angular 4 to angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052007/issue-after-upgrading-angular-4-to-angular-8)

I have also read Angular.io but not working for me. 
So I upgared it to Angular 5. I did not get issue in console but when I run application Ui is not displaying.

Do I need to convert system.js to CLI first before upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to.

First create a new CLI project and copy module by module application source code.

Then you have to change the task in systemsjs and try to see how the they fit with CLI.

It all depends on how complex your application is structured.

Comment: My application is very complex. Is there any other way to upgrade it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

It would be better if you create a new project and move modules into the new project. Then based on complexity of your current application configure your `package.json, angular.json and tsconfig.json` and install packages using npm command `npm install`

[Move project from SystemJS to Angular CLI / Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738595/move-project-from-systemjs-to-angular-cli-webpack)